# Recover PHP file from CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, gnome

I've just accidentally overwritten a PHP file on my centOS Server and i don't have a backup of that file, Is there anyway i can recover the old revision of the file some how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you overwrote the file (and not just deleted it), your only hope is that your editor saved a backup file of the original. If not, it's gone.

If I may, I recommend using a Source Control Management (such as Git, SVN etc.) if you need versions of your source files preserved.

Comment: ok thanks i was editing a PHP file but overwrote the wrong file. I can't see any cached versions on my Windows PC or the server it was uploaded too. Thanks anyway